# How do i use proxy with requests.session

Tags: python, session, python-requests, proxy

Hi i am trying to do an action with a session like this:
`with requests.Session() as ses:`
`s = ses.get(f"URL")`

my proxy format is: http://username:password@url_of_proxyprovider:port

i tried using in this case: `ses.proxies.update(proxy)` but it didnt work.
also tried this, but didnt work: `s.proxies = {'proxy'}`
also tried adding proxy like this: `s = ses.get(f"url", proxies=proxy)`
its always done through my IP and not through the proxy.

Comment: Did you try to set it correctly like `ses.proxies = {'http':'http://username:password@url_of_proxyprovider:port', 'https':'http://username:password@url_of_proxyprovider:port'}` **before** you do the ses.get() request.

Comment: Yup, that did the thing, i only put one format instead of two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting comment to answer.

The correct way to do it:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session
    session.proxies = {
        'http': 'http://username:password@url_of_proxyprovider:port',
        'https': 'http://username:password@url_of_proxyprovider:port'
    }

    url = 'http://mywebsite.com/example'
    response = session.get(url)
```

If you want to proxy FTP also, you can add it to the proxies dictionary:

```
    session.proxies = {
        'http': 'http://username:password@url_of_proxyprovider:port',
        'https': 'http://username:password@url_of_proxyprovider:port',
        'ftp': 'http://username:password@url_of_proxyprovider:port'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some example of it.

```
    import requests
    proxies = {'http': 'http://10.11.4.254:3128'}
    s = requests.session()
    s.proxies.update(proxies)
    s.get("http://www.example.com")
```

or with each session request you can pass proxy

```
    import requests
    proxies = {'http': 'http://10.11.4.254:3128'}
    s = requests.session()
    s.get("http://www.example.com",proxies=proxies)
```